# How to assign a value to a symbol given the name in a string

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Given the name of a symbol in a string, how can one assign a value to it, more than once?  For example, suppose I want to define a symbol whose name is the value of `varname` and I want to assign it a value:

```
varname = "foo"
Symbol[varname]=5
```

That does not work because Mathematica thinks you are trying to assign a value to Symbol, which is protected.  This will work if `foo` is undefined:

```
Evaluate[Symbol[varname]]=5
```

Ok.  But it will not work a second time:

```
Evaluate[Symbol[varname]]=6
```

When the left hand side is evaluated it evaluates to 5 and Mathematica complains that you are trying to assign the value 6 to the raw object 5.  I want to access the symbol `foo` on the left hand side of the assignment, not the value of `foo`.  Can this be done?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: See `ToExpression`.

Comment: `Alan` -- Thanks.  I looked at `ToExpression` before posting, but it kept evaluating to a point where it was trying to assign to a value.  I found the answer using `ToExpression` with `Hold` as an optional argument.  Also, this was helpful [(1)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2926/mapthread-gives-different-results-from-toexpression-when-trying-to-assign-variab).  I'll post more later.

Comment: `varname = "foo"; ToExpression[varname <> "=5"]; foo

Comment: `Alan` -- Yes, thanks, that will work after all.  I was using Evaluate on the right hand side, which necessitated a Hold argument.  Your way is simpler and better, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of methods, working on either the string or the variable name.

```
i = Function[{f, g}, Clear[f]; Evaluate@Symbol[f] = g];
i["foo", 5];
foo
i["foo", 6];
foo
```

> ```
> 5
> 6
> ```

```
h = Function[{f, g}, f = g, {HoldFirst}];
h[foo, 5];
foo
h[foo, 6];
foo
```

> ```
> 5
> 6
> ```

Comment: `Chris` Yes, thanks the first version is what I was interested in where the name is in a string.  It works because `Clear` not only can take the variable name, but also that name in a string constant.  Both this and the method suggested by Alan are good solutions, thank you.